# MYSQL - Join 3 tables Grouping By Month Including Empty Months

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

I have 3 tables: T_AUDITS, T_MONTHS AND T_REGIONS.

I'm trying to get number of 'Audits' grouping by Months and Regions, including Zero when not exist an Audit for that month.

My query only gets the months that have Audits. I am not able to get the months with 0 audits.

```
SELECT 
 MON.MON_DESC,
 REG.REG_ID,
 COUNT(AUD.AUD_ID) 
FROM
 T_MONTHS MON 
 LEFT JOIN T_AUDITS AUD 
   ON (
     MON.MON_ID = MONTH(AUD.AUD_START_DATE)
   ) 
   RIGHT JOIN T_REGIONS REG 
   ON (
     REG.REG_ID = AUD.AUD_REGION
   )  
GROUP BY    MON.MON_ID, REG.REG_ID
ORDER BY REG.REG_ID,
 MON.MON_ID
```

---

I get:

```
MON_NAME  |REG_ID        |COUNT(AUD.AUD_ID) |
----------|--------------|------------------|
January   |AMERICA       |52                |
February  |AMERICA       |51                |
March     |AMERICA       |57                |
April     |AMERICA       |66                |
May       |AMERICA       |54                |
January   |ASIA          |58                |
February  |ASIA          |29                |
April     |ASIA          |71                |
May       |EUROPE        |59                |
```

---

I'm trying to get:

```
MON_NAME  |REG_ID        |COUNT(AUD.AUD_ID) |
----------|--------------|------------------|
January   |AMERICA       |52                |
February  |AMERICA       |51                |
March     |AMERICA       |57                |
April     |AMERICA       |66                |
May       |AMERICA       |54                |
January   |ASIA          |58                |
February  |ASIA          |29                |
March     |ASIA          |0                 |
April     |ASIA          |59                |
May       |ASIA          |0                 |
January   |EUROPE        |0                 |
February  |EUROPE        |0                 |
March     |EUROPE        |0                 |
April     |EUROPE        |0                 |
May       |EUROPE        |79                |
```

any ideas? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: In my own experience, I actually prefer to create a static table with each row as a month. Much easier (and more efficient) to `JOIN` on this table than to try and do logic to include Months that aren't part of the joined data. You can `JOIN` on this table and replace `NULL` (no records) with `0`.

Comment: I would suggest `COALESCE()`, but I don't see how you'll get your `REG_ID` without `AUD_REGION`.

Comment: @Santi Isn't that what `T_MONTHS` is?

Comment: @Barmar Doh. Didn't read closely enough. Nice suggestion with the `CROSS JOIN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a `CROSS JOIN` to get all the month and region combinations, then use `LEFT JOIN` to get the audits.

```
SELECT 
 MON.MON_DESC,
 REG.REG_ID,
 IFNULL(COUNT(AUD.AUD_ID), 0) AS count
FROM T_MONTHS MON 
CROSS JOIN T_REGIONS REG
LEFT JOIN T_AUDIT AUD ON MONTH(AUD.AUD_START_DATE) = MON.MON_ID AND REG.REG_ID = AUD.AUD_REGION
GROUP BY REG.REG_ID, MON.MON_ID
ORDER BY REG.REG_ID, MON.MON_ID
```

Comment: It works!!.. Thank you very much, I had never used cross join before. You just gave me a good lesson.